# How do I add an item to the array taking into account the months of the year?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an response with this structure.

```
{
"records": [
{
"patientName": "CECILIA NONE ANCINEZ DE LOPEZ",
"patientProductCode": "MO000250",
"patientProduct": "RUXOLITINIB 15 MG TABLETA",
"patientFirstDispatch": "18/11/2021",
"dispatch": [
{
"month": 6,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-6"
},
{
"month": 4,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-4"
},
{
"month": 3,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-3"
},
{
"month": 2,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-2"
},
{
"month": 1,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-1"
},
{
"month": 12,
"year": 2021,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2021-12"
}
]
},
]
}
```

and I also have this json with the last 7 months.

```
{
"months": [
{
"month": "June",
"position": 6,
"year": 2022,
"period": "2022-6"
},
{
"month": "May",
"position": 5,
"year": 2022,
"period": "2022-5"
},
{
"month": "April",
"position": 4,
"year": 2022,
"period": "2022-4"
},
{
"month": "March",
"position": 3,
"year": 2022,
"period": "2022-3"
},
{
"month": "February",
"position": 2,
"year": 2022,
"period": "2022-2"
},
{
"month": "January",
"position": 1,
"year": 2022,
"period": "2022-1"
},
{
"month": "December",
"position": 12,
"year": 2021,
"period": "2021-12"
}
]
}
```

---

I need to add an object inside the dispatch array with the property
"quantity" = 0 when the "period" property doesn't match between the dispatch array and the months array.

---

the result of comparing between the array "months" and "dispatch" should return something like this.

### An object was added at position 1 of the "dispatch" array.

```
{
"records": [
{
"patientName": "CECILIA NONE ANCINEZ DE LOPEZ",
"patientProductCode": "MO000250",
"patientProduct": "RUXOLITINIB 15 MG TABLETA",
"patientFirstDispatch": "18/11/2021",
"dispatch": [
{
"month": 6,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-6"
},
{
"month": 5,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 0,
"period": "2022-5"
},
{
"month": 4,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-4"
},
{
"month": 3,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-3"
},
{
"month": 2,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-2"
},
{
"month": 1,
"year": 2022,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2022-1"
},
{
"month": 12,
"year": 2021,
"quantity": 30,
"period": "2021-12"
}
]
},
]
}
```

I tried to do it but I could not add the objects correctly.
could you help me with this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by period property does not match?

Comment: means that the "period" property of the "dispatch" array does not match the "period" property of the "months" array.

sorry if i don't explain well.

Comment: please share you implemented code, so we can check for suggesting a suitable solution with your implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach()` and `array_filter()` for searching, then add new record to dispatch. Same as :

```
foreach ($objectMonths->months as $arrayMonth) {
    foreach ($objectDispatch->records as $record) {
        $exist = array_filter($record->dispatch, fn($mon) => $mon->period === $arrayMonth->period);
        if (!count($exist)) {
            $month = date('m', strtotime($arrayMonth->period));
            $record->dispatch[] = (object)['month' => (int)$month, 'year' => $arrayMonth->year, 'quantity' => 0, 'period' => $arrayMonth->period];
            usort($record->dispatch, fn($a, $b) => $a->period < $b->period);
        }
    }
}
```

Code sample in [here](https://onlinephp.io?s=lVTxa-IwFP59sP8hF4S20LK2znHcpodz3ejQOg4PjolIbCPLmI2XRjiR_e_30lo11RWsQsPL933v5X2vufu5fFteXjTeM54-sGxJZPyG2sjYYEFjLpIM_0DjDYY4o6mMyIJCAPeCXtgPuygaRgHqRr0wCl7RQ4D6w5fgFdsl_EXwZBXLHk9y1mDouq7fco8AavPX7z_DfjgKo_AeeS00eEKj7n0_GHX36EcmMlkWqTje9yvPu_Jd3wNQst-Aghc8lWp5Y-M1JQJWAPNt_HdFUsnkGgJNF5SpYDxRWmrbucGf9p57fRb3WuM2z-I2Na5_FtfXuN5ZXE_naom9erLneJB5Aj_jdjs_A6WTFdOTa2a6F_h5lVJlJ8-YZDw9YU-tH3hA1jq9VU9v6fTuUrAPXaBqca2nkF_AfGkCVZ9rjcWPdCZWRFROUfW71mD8TNJjiarttT7jBxrTxYyKikbV_pN-527z2TuN5cF9oeyfJnBjJNTU7hJrD9-NxxG42FHQOReUgKKpcZxOMU6IZKhBhCDrPG6hzeUFgqfKKpM7ne0llhOL9Y6kngb9xzIJJeWi0zn7kFSYW6TTKa8UG81TswE1WKjdQWrhdIrmoHa7fVhSGVdnKZOwOTK_xXyVSrPIZ2k15HXk54M6EiKpaSwMG2VSSC7ZAlp0Qv5QPxeoljyegJpZtMMaG7m-oao3WSqtIp-NDOV3HtaSqChslp9_DnAhUCQ_xhfxSaWmVcaF_KqZxEaNWdFOsmvmHcROdfCzWMIL_vARp3IqvvR67E72yazb_w%2C%2C&v=8.1.6)

Comment: I really appreciate your help.
⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐

your code solved my problem
I just made a little change in the usort(); to avoid an error.

----------------
`usort($record->dispatch, fn ($a, $b) => $a->period < $b->period ? 1 : -1);`